# Capacity theory beginner resources

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, self-learning, book-recommendation

I'm currently studying a book on shape optimization: [Variation et optimisation de formes: Une analyse géométrique By Antoine Henrot, Michel Pierre](http://ebookee.org/Variation-et-optimisation-de-formes-Une-analyse-g-om-trique-By-Antoine-Henrot-Michel-Pierre_306986.html). The book introduces at some point capacity, and uses this to define quasi-open sets, quasi continuous functions, and these results apply very nice to approximation theorems in Sobolev spaces. As a remark, this is one of the few mathematical concepts I searched on Google, and found nothing like a wikipedia article or some sites which contain good knowledge about this subject in a beginner's terms.

The capacity is defined for compact sets first like this:

> For $K\subset \Bbb{R}^N$ compact, we denote $cap(K)=\inf \{ \|v\|_{H^1(\Bbb{R}^N)}^2 : v \in C_0^\infty(\Bbb{R}^N),\ v \geq 1 \text{ on }K\}<\infty$. $C_0^\infty$ is the space of smooth functions with compact support.

From here, capacity extends to open sets, by taking the supremum on the capacities of compact sets contained in an open set.

> The relative capacity is defined for a compact $K$ subset of a bounded open set $D\subset \Bbb{R}^N$ by $cap_D(K)=\inf\{ \int_D |\nabla v|^2 : v \in C_0^\infty(D),\ v \geq 1 \text{ on }K\}<\infty$.

I understood pretty well the Lebesgue measure by finding a way to visualize it (surely, this is not hard). I would like to know if there is something similar for capacity. How could I visualize it or understand it? How it relates to the physical reality? For example, what does the capacity of a ball or box in $\Bbb{R}^3,\Bbb{R}^n$ mean (for Lebesgue measure is the "volume")?

I would like to know if there are some books which treat the capacity subject in a manner like measure theory books do it, with many proved properties and some study problems to understand it better.

> How can I understand capacity related to some physical aspect (shape, smoothness, finess...)? What are some good references for a beginner in the field?

Comment: Have you looked at the books by Gustave Choquet? He's the inventor and writes extremely well, I think. I'm pretty sure his three-volume *Cours d'analyse* contains what you're looking for, and he also has the book *[Theory of capacities: Research on modern potential theory and Dirichlet problem](http://books.google.com/books?id=2dQ-AAAAIAAJ)*.

Comment: I haven't looked into those books. I'll search for them. Thank you.

Comment: A more modern reference containing the basics would be §30 of Kechris, *[Classical descriptive set theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=pPv9KCEkklsC)*.

Comment: This is very nice too :) Thank you.

Comment: I can recommend the book "Variational Analysis in Sobolev and BV spaces" by Attouch et. al.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there is no answer posted, I will post some references I found meanwhile, apart of those presented in the comments:

- Juha Heinonen, Tero Kilpelainen, Olli Martio: [Nonlinear Potential Theory of Degenerate Elliptic Equations](http://books.google.com/books/about/Nonlinear_Potential_Theory_of_Degenerate.html?id=pp0HXuZd7R8C)
- Naum Samoĭlovich Landkof: [Foundations of modern potential theory](http://books.google.com/books/about/Foundations_of_modern_potential_theory.html?id=ZAqoAAAAIAAJ)
- David R. Adams, Lars I. Hedberg: [Function Spaces and Potential Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=KmyomBiXc-4C)
- David R. Adams: [Potential and Capacity before and after Wiener](http://books.google.com/books?id=E8SRzHI0oiYC&pg=PA63)